# cassandra heap out of memory exception

Tags: cassandra

I am mostly getting this heap exception in my cassandra seed server. I have a cluster of cassandra created with multiple data centres.

HEre is the exception

```
ERROR [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.0.1.188] 2015-10-17 15:53:59,807 CassandraDaemon.java:223 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.0.1.188,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2015-10-17 15:53:59,807 AbstractCommitLogService.java:105 - Out of 4 commit log syncs over the past 1356s with average duration of 20691.50ms, 2 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 31383.00ms
ERROR [Thread-2] 2015-10-17 15:54:25,876 CassandraDaemon.java:223 - Exception in thread Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:481) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:311) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at org.apache.thrift.TException.<init>(TException.java:39) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException.<init>(TTransportException.java:64) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TCustomServerSocket.acceptImpl(TCustomServerSocket.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TCustomServerSocket.acceptImpl(TCustomServerSocket.java:36) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerTransport.accept(TServerTransport.java:60) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer.serve(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:110) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer$ThriftServerThread.run(ThriftServer.java:137) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-36] 2015-10-17 15:55:02,461 JVMStabilityInspector.java:94 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-35] 2015-10-17 15:55:02,461 CassandraDaemon.java:223 - Exception in thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-35,5,main]
```

please help

I have 16 gb machine with these setting in my cassandra-env.sh file

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="10G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
```

My cassandra version is 2.1.8 and I am using nodejs client to write to cassandra and spark to process the data

Comment: Cassandra OOM is the symptom of a more insidious problem. To help you, we need much more information. Can you give us the nodetool status ? What is your schema ? Are you using any clustering key ? What kind of query do you perform ?

Comment: can I query cause my cassandra to crash? I have 3 clustering keys and 2 partition keys. I have the memory dump with me. Will analyse and let you know the reason. Still there were not many rows in cassandra and my seed and nodes had 10 gm of ram allocated to cassandra so I guess, out of momory should not make sense.

Comment: When querying very large partition there is a risk of out of memory because cassandra needs to map the full partition in memory to look up into it. You must not have partitions bigger than 100.000 columns and 100Mb. Could it be the problem ?

Comment: My partition key is fairly small with 2 columns. My clustering columns consists of only 4 columns. Thus this should not be the issue in my case

Comment: Can we make out something from the logs of cassandra that I have posted above?

Comment: How much row with the same partition key ?

Comment: well not much. I have a randomnum as part of partition key which is from (0-10) and appname which are around 20. So the total of 30 unique partition key

Comment: Also I have 2 data centres, and 3 nodes in each data centre with 1 seed in each dc and replication factor of 2 for my keyspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97886/discussion-between-dinemartine-and-nipun).